# Casting pointer from base type to child type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm building a simple game design for a project of mine. I have the following classes:

```
class Character
{
public: 
   virtual void Display();
   virtual void SetParameters( char* param, ... );
};

class NonPlayableCharacter : public Character
{

public:
   virtual void Display();
   virtual void SetParameters( char* paaram, ... );
   int GetNPCState();
}
```

And then I have a bunch of classes that derive either from Character or NonPlayableCharacter. I define it like so:

```
std::vector<Character*> _allChar;
```

My problem is that at any given time I would want to perform some operation on one of the element of the vector. So getting an element out of the vector I can't directly call the method `GetNPCState()` because the element in the vector are of Character* type. So doing this:

```
_allChar[0]->GetNPCState();
```

doesn't work. So I tried doing it with the famous dynamic_cast:

```
NonPlayableCharacter* test = dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0]);
test->GetNPCState();
```

The problem with this last attempt is that `GetNPCState()` crashes because the object is null, and I know for a fact (via debugging) that _allChar[0] isn't null.

Comment: You get a null pointer when the object you are trying to cast to `NonPlayableCharacter` isn't in fact a `NonPlayableCharacter`. Probably some of the objects in the vector are directly derived from `Character`.

Comment: As an aside, I work with a component(s) which uses many vectors of pointers. It has caused a helluva lot of trouble for me, as this vector ends up sometimes with pointers to deleted memory, and it leads to memory corruption. I guess that you use a pointer vector because you are using it polymorphically, and/or the objects are shared. In either case I would HIGHLY recommend changing your vector to hold a shared pointer type (`std::shared_ptr` for example) or change your vector to `boost::ptr_vector` (which is great for both scenarios). Good luck with the game!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several types of casts in C++ (4), of which 2 are of interests here:

- `static_cast` assumes that you know what you are doing
- `dynamic_cast` checks, at runtime, that you "guessed" right

*Note: simplified, as `dynamic_cast` also allows cross-casts and casts involving virtual bases.*

There are 3 versions of `dynamic_cast`, really, depending on the nature of the target:

- if the target is a reference (ie `dynamic_cast<T&>(u)`), then if the check fails `dynamic_cast` throws a `std::bad_cast` exception
- if the target is a pointer (ie `dynamic_cast<T*>(p)`), then if the checks fails `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer
- finally, as a special case, if the target is `void*`, then `dynamic_cast` instead returns the address of the full object

In this case, you may:

- switch from `dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0])->getNPCState()` to
  `dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter&>(*_allChar[0]).getNPCState()`, and let the exception propagates
- test the result of the cast (`NonPlayableCharacter* test` here) for non-nullity

Answer (score 5):

After

```
NonPlayableCharacter* test = dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0]);
```

you should check if `test` is `NULL`. Even if `_allChar[0]` isn't NULL, the `dynamic_cast` can return `NULL` if the object it points to isn't a `NonPlayableCharacter`.

So the correct version would be:

```
NonPlayableCharacter* test = dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0]);
if (test)
{
   test->GetNPCState();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` if cast is impossible. Check what is inside `_allChar[0]`. You could make function like `getType()` where returns object predefined type id and then use `static_cast`:

```
if (_allChar[0]->getType() == TYPE_NO_PLAYER) {
    static_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0])->getNpcState();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to test the `dynamic_cast` for success. It returns a null pointer upon failure:

```
NonPlayableCharacter* test = dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0]);
if (test) test->GetNCPState();
```

The problem could be that your first element does not point to a `NonPlayableCharacter` object.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` when its argument doesn't point to a `NonPlayableCharacter` (so the first element in the array probably points to some other subclass of `Character`) - so you need to check for `NULL` after the cast. However, using `dynamic_cast` might be indicative of a design problem. Perhaps you should instead have a virtual method on `Character` that is called e.g. `PerformMainActionInGameLoop()` and is overridden appropriately in the different subclasses?

Answer (score 2):

To get a child pointer from a base pointer you do have to use `dynamic_cast`. Its behaviour is the following:

- If the pointer points to a `Child*` allocated with `new Child` then `dynamic_cast<Child*>` returns a `Child*`
- If the pointer points to something else, then `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL`.

Your problem is that either you didn't allocate with `new`, or your object is of a different type.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better OO solution to using dynamic_cast, but the whole point of using this cast is that it will return a NULL pointer if the cast fails.

So check for NULL before you call GetNPCState();

```
NonPlayableCharacter* test = dynamic_cast<NonPlayableCharacter*>(_allChar[0]);
if( test != NULL )
{   
     test->GetNPCState(); 
}
```